# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 Client with Gitlab failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I am trying to integrate Spring Security 5 OAuth2/OIDC with GitLab in my project, and follow the official sample codes [oauth2login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login), add my Gitlab configuration like the following.

```
security:
 oauth2:
  client:
    registration:

      gitlab:
        client-id: 0cef9527091bb2faec01610a0fb330e3a915672110cf3298ff3aadceaa8ab11f
        client-secret: fd84439d06f7a2dabb5d5a64ac478211ab4009aa0fa62d478661a52f4234de72
        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        redirectUriTemplate: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
        scope:
          - openid
          - api
        clientName: GitLab
    provider:
     gitlab:
        authorization-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize
        token-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/token
        user-info-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/userinfo
        jwk-set-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/discovery/keys
```

And I created an application in my Gitlab settings account, set it authorization callback url as: **http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gitlab**.

When I ran the application via `mvn spring-boot:run`. And click the **Gitlab**,  click **Authorize** button in the GitLab authorize page.

Then the page return to **http://localhost:8080/login**,  and I got exception in the console like the following:

```
  at position 15931.
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.parse(JSONObjectUtils.java:75) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-5.4.jar:5.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.parse(JWKSet.java:304) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-5.4.jar:5.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:145) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-5.4.jar:5.4]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

It seems it did not redirect to the desired page, but the Gitlab login instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue, but I believe an error is here:

```
user-info-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/userinfo
```

Which should be:

```
user-info-uri: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user
```

Per here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html

Comment: also need to adjust the
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.user-name-attribute=username

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with same issue for last two days, finally found a working solution:

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.authorization-uri=https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.token-uri=https://gitlab.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.user-info-uri=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.user-name-attribute=username
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.jwk-set-uri=https://gitlab.com/oauth/discovery/keys

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.client-secret=YOUR_SECRET
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gitlab
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.scope=read_user
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab.client-name=GitLab
```

Gitlab app configuration:

[image: gitlab config]

Of course remember to change `localhost:8080` to your real app address. This one, however, works fine for local development.

Comment: When I used Gitlab at that moment, I think there was an issue that Gitlab protected some discovery configuration URL by default.